ListView Items Not Displaying but Responding to Clicks in Fragment
I am using Android Studio with Java to develop an application that includes an activity containing a fragment (let's call it PromotionsFragment). In this fragment, I have implemented a sticky headers ListView. The sticky headers ensure that the header remains visible while scrolling through the list. The implementation works perfectly on my current device, with both the list items and the OnItemClickListener functioning as expected.
Working StickyHeadersListview Android 7
However, I encountered an issue on devices with newer android versions (9 and above) while older versions were working just fine, where:
•   The list appears empty with no visible child items.
•   Despite the empty appearance, the OnItemClickListener is triggered correctly when I tap on           the screen at the position of an invisible item.
•   The list is filled and functional, but the items' text or content is not being displayed.
Empty StickyHeadersListView Android 14
I've Tried:
•   Ensuring that the adapter is properly set and data is being passed correctly.
•   Changing the sticky header ListView to a normal ListView, but the issue persists.
•   Verifying that there are no errors or warnings in the logcat.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with ListView or sticky headers ListView where items are not visible but still respond to clicks? What might be causing the text or views to be invisible, and how can I resolve this issue?
Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

you should share the code too so we can read it to help

you should use recyclerview  instead of listview, as has many advantages over listview

I'm not sure as to what to share, it is a big application and I cant seem to find  the source of the problem @bhavykhanna

@Nixkr the data setting part I guess, and you should do it in recycler you will have much more control over the data
